# Linux Compiz like effects on HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Are there any jQuery plugins or a JavaScript library in general to implement Linux Compiz like effects on HTML elements?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe. HTML5 goes a long way when it comes to 3D effects but of course, there are limits to what it can do.

The main problem is that you can't directly add HTML elements to the canvas. For example, you can't add an `iframe` to it and then manipulate the result by rotation/transforming it.

For a great example of what you can do, visit http://ro.me/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with Compiz like effects, but there is a lot of nice effects in jQuery by default: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/, and in the UI extension: http://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 0):

Like this? http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39519/talks/gperf/index.html
This uses only html5 and css animation (and also a bit js but not for the displaying, for the navigating)